# Crashlytics updated to Fabric: Unable to copy dSYM

Tags: xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I've updated my project from Crashlytics to Fabric. I've followed all steps in the Fabric Mac app but now my app simple won't build more than once without cleaning.

When I use Product > Clean, I can build my app once. The next time I try, building fails again.

**What can I do to fix this issue?**

```
2015-07-17 12:10:58.602 run[10802:603564]
Fabric.framework/run 1.3.16

2015-07-17 12:10:58.958 run[10802:603564]
Unable to copy dSYM at path /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-byhgrsorkjornnaplkksbbzmvfel/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
to path /Users/username/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac/5b91b14e832a7b1c29441ec5ba109810/builds/86A88558-0818-40BB-9EF5-B4816707A076/appname dev.app.dSYM
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “DWARF” doesn’t exist." UserInfo=0x10010c960
{
    NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-byhgrsorkjornnaplkksbbzmvfel/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appname dev.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF, NSUserStringVariant=(Copy),
    NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/username/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac/5b91b14e832a7b1c29441ec5ba109810/builds/86A88558-0818-40BB-9EF5-B4816707A076/appname dev.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF, NSFilePath=/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-byhgrsorkjornnaplkksbbzmvfel/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ticketveiling dev.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF, 
    NSUnderlyingError=0x10010c6a0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"
}

Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I got the same problem today. I think the cocoapod spec may be messed up, as the message says "Fabric.framework/run 1.3.16" but the pod update output says "Using Fabric (1.2.8)". I had to remove Fabric pods completely to fix the build errors. I will probably try going back to the embedded version that the app manages.

Comment: I even tried pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.3' but that doesn't work. I also tried installing an older version of cocoapods but it also gives the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like updating Fabric/Crashlytics solved my problem!

```
pod update 'Crashlytics'
Installing Crashlytics 3.1.0 (was 3.0.11)
```

**Update:** I guess I spoke a bit too soon. The issue isn't completely fixed, but at least I have to clean a lot less than before.

Answer (score -3):

add cleaning to your build scripts

Comment: Let's call this plan B